# input file cannot be found

Tags: java

I am just messing around with reading input files with java until I got stumped at the most basic of steps... finding the input file!

The input.txt file is in the same directory as my class file that is calling it yet eclipse still gives me an error that it cant be found:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException"

My code:

```
package pa;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Project {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("input.txt");
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
 }
}
```

input.txt is in the same package, same folder and everything. I'm confused :(

Comment: Try creating a file and see if newly created file is made in same folder. When you give path like "input.txt" java compiler makes is $PWD/input.txt where $PWD is path from where class file was executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about eclipse, but in netbeans the path doesn't start from the package (folder) your class is in, but the root folder of your project. to find that file in netbeans, you would have to put `new File("src/pa/input.txt")`.

Comment: note that instead of `/` and `\`, `File.separator` should be used, to allow portability.

Comment: No problem. Also, I'd recommend using a FileInputStream rather than a scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the absolute path of the file, for example:

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:\\My Documents\\User\\input.txt");
```

Also, declare the `main()` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

Normally you'd want to catch and handle the exception, but for now just throw it.

Answer (score 1):

When using eclipse, the working directory is the project directory, not the directory of the class.

You can get the working directory in the following method:

```
File f = new File(".");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

The error "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException" can be resolved by exception handling in you main() method. Add the following command in your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
```

Run the program and you should get the input.txt file location.

You can learn more about exception handling [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

See the folder where the class files are being generated. If the input.txt file is not in that folder then put it there and try running your code again.

Comment: It was in the same folder so I'm not sure why this happened. I ended up making a new project and just left the class with the default package name and it worked... why this worked? I will never know. The input was always in the same folder as the class so I dont know what happened

Comment: in the same folder as the java files. did you check the folder where the .class files were getting generated?